# Tail taking long time to run

Tags: python, linux, unix, tail

When I do a `tail` operation it usually takes about ~0.01. However, there's one file that I have that is less than 10MB that takes about 100 times the average. Even multi-GB files finish around the 'normal' time.

Here is what I'm running:

```
t0 = time.time()
s = subprocess.check_output(['tail', '-%s' % str(n), file]).decode('unicode_escape')
if self.verbose: print ('LastNLines: %.5f' % (time.time()-t0))
```

Why might this be taking so long to issue the tail command on this particular file, or, in a general case, why might certain files take much longer than others to `tail` ?

Comment: Can you reproduce it when you run just this snippet (not your full program) on just this file? Is it a regular file?  Does it have abnormally long lines?

Comment: I'll bet it's abnormally long lines.